# My C# application is crashing or hung

Tags: c#, .net, crash

While using my C# Windows Application, it is hung and goes to not responding mode. Sometimes it throws DR.Watson debugger error.

I have mentioned the error details got from windows error report,

```
**Event Type:   Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1000
Date:       11/12/2012
Time:       1:01:58 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   My PC
Description:
Faulting application aod_gfvt.exe, version 1.0.0.0, stamp 50a0a39d, faulting module 
wininet.dll, version 7.0.6000.17114, stamp 503bc6a7, debug? 0, fault address 
 0x00004606.
For more information, see Help and Support Center at 
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.**
```

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: How did you imagine us to help you without providing source code ???

Comment: looks like your problem is in `aod_gfvt.exe` at address `0x00004606` show some code

Comment: problem with `wininet.dll`..

Answer (score 1):

You will get no information from Watson log.

Add global exception handling to your application or application domain.

For example [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

When you add global exception handler, you will get more info. Watson is intercepting your error because some critical unhanded exception has crashed your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use windbg and make a crash dump. and look up which thread cause crash.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx